# ForeverJS getting EADDRINUSE error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, express, forever

I'm a novice with Ubuntu and node express. But I've got enough knowledge that I was able to setup a static web server with an REST API running along side it, using Forever. I also successfully installed Samba to edit the files directly from my Windows machine.

About a month ago, I got my static website up and running. It has a form on it that does a jQuery POST to the REST API service. Using Forever, I had two node processes running, one for the static website service, and the other for the API service, BOTH listening on the same port 80.

This was all working fine a month ago, I could load the static website, and submit a form and I would get my email notification via my API service. But about a week ago, everything went down, including my Samba file share. Logged into my server and 'forever list' was empty. Ok, so I figured the server must have restarted without me knowing. I then start up both my services again:

```
root@xxxxx:~/www/web/ourwedding# forever start staticserver.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: staticserver.js
root@xxxxx:~/www/web/ourwedding# forever start apiserver.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: apiserver.js
```

I run forever list:

```
root@xxxxx:~/www/web/ourwedding# forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command         script          forever pid id logfile                 uptime
data:    [0] IKkB /usr/bin/nodejs staticserver.js 469     471    /root/.forever/IKkB.log 0:0:0:26.307
data:    [1] APxV /usr/bin/nodejs apiserver.js    479     481    /root/.forever/APxV.log STOPPED
```

I see the error and go to check it out:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at EventEmitter.app.listen (/root/www/web/ourwedding/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:595:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/www/web/ourwedding/apiserver.js:69:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

I then spend the next couple of hours trying to figure out what is going on. From what I have found so far, that error is because I'm running both services on the same port... BUT it was working fine before? I have to run them on the same port, because I'm doing a AJAX POST to the same domain.

Things I've tried:

1. deleting the .forever folder in root
2. restarting the server
3. killall -9 nodejs

Things I've not tried:

1. a different solution to forever
2. combining my static web server and api server into one service.

I guess I'm just wondering if I'm going crazy or if I did something a month ago that I just cant for the live of me remember, that allowed me to run both services on the same port.

Any help or suggestions would be welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Forever... Are you sure you are killing the server correctly? I'm sure you know, `EADDRINUSE` means that the address is already use.

Comment: Restart your system, maybe it will help. `EADDRINUSE` means that you have process already started and you are trying to start again.

Answer (score 0):

Argh... and the answer is:
my memory is crap :-)

I decided I should just combine my two services in one, and as I'm going through the code, I notice that I had already combined them!!! I'm such an idiot. Thank you for those that tried to help, but in this case its definitely user error.

As mentioned before, EADDRINUSE is thrown because both services was trying to listen on the same port... I just thought that I had solved it somehow without combining my files.